# How can i get dot button in calculator app

Tags: android

I am making a calculator in android, and I have make a button of dot operator, whenever I am pressing that button, it is not showing dot on screen like it should show 2.4 but it's showing 24 , what can I do???.I have used edit text field for showing result.

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [Refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154895/android-edittext-show-both-comma-and-dot-as-possible-separator-in-case-of-numbe)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for...Try the below code

```
Edt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

[See this link too](http://www.startofandroid.com/en/lessons/complete-list/225-lesson-19-creating-a-simple-calculator.html) and [refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551757/allow-only-number-and-period-in-edit-text-in-android)

Hope this helps you..